# Read/write access, POSIX permissions and sandbox during drag tracking

Tags: cocoa, posix, sandbox

I have an issue where I'm trying to determine if a directory has write access during drag tracking but calling methods like NSFileManager.isWritableFileAtPath doesn't work because they return the write permissions under the sandbox. When the drag is complete the current process (my app) will assume normal access to the directory (as dictated by the POSIX permissions) but I need to know ahead of time what the actual permissions are so I can reflect this in the drag operation cursor.

I found how to get the POSIX permissions using NSFileManager but I couldn't find out how to read just the write permission portion from the value (which came back as a decimal like 420). I thought there would be some simple bit masking or helper functions to convert the values but I couldn't find them anywhere.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define`s are available in the include file `<sys/stat.h>` - see `chmod` in section 2 of the manual. The integer 420 is rw-r--r-- - r/w by owner, read everyone else.

Comment: I see the defines and read man chmod but I still don't understand how you can derive a single write-owner mask from any integer, such as 420. For example there is "S_IWUSR 0000200". Does that mean the 3rd digit of any number is user writeable if it's "2"? Thanks.

Comment: The `#define` constants are the bit masks you refer to in your question. Use bitwise-and operations etc. to test individual permissions e.g. `if( (permissions & S_IWUSR) != 0 ) ...`

Comment: Thanks, I get it now but I think the sandbox is not returning the same permissions as I see in the Finder. For example /Developer is returning 509 (from the NSFilePosixPermissions attributes key) which with S_IWUSR is saying no write, even though Finder says read/write (stat /Developers says drwxrwxr-x). That means I don't even know how to get the original permissions outside the sandbox.

Comment: 509 decimal is 1FD hex or 111111101 binary - i.e. rwxrwxr-x. S_IWUSR is 0000200 octal or 010000000 binary. Bitwise-and those, using `&`, and you get 010000000, which is non-zero - in this case indicating user write permission.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the correct values here. "stat /System" returns "drwxr-xr-x" which is writeable by the owner correct? I get the integer 493 (octal 755) which is owner writable (bitwise with S_IWUSR confirms this) but the Finder get info window says read only and sure enough I can not write to this directory. That explains why I'm confused I think. Is your /System like this also? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found out what happened here. The current logged in user isn't the owner of /System so I still get errors even though I read the "writable by owner" bit correctly. If that's correct how can I compare if the files owner is the same as the current user? Sorry I don't know much at all about UNIX permissions apparently.

Comment: For ownership you need to look up *uid* and `NSFileManager`'s `NSFileOwnerAccountID`. However your comments indicate you may have a different problem - the permissions indicated under the *sandbox* **are** the permissions applicable to your code, the underlying file system permissions are not relevant *per se*. If you want to determine what access your code will be granted use `access` (section 2 of the manual).